# Is there a way to get list of files scanned for a RedShift query referencing tables in Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We have a query which is performing an aggregation, like:
SELECT t.date, COUNT(*) AS rec_count
FROM our_schema.log_data t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY t.date;

I know we can get the quantity of data scanned by this query, but I would like to get the list of DISTINCT files that this query has accessed in S3.

I've been digging around for a bit, but can't find a system view that would give that information, and I'm not sure how we could use $path with the query to get the info.

Thoughts?

Comment: STL_S3LIST doesn’t have what you are looking for?

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was a way but couldnt find it after searching for a couple of hours. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL_S3LIST should have what you need (per comment exchange).